# How can I get the HTML code of a webpage after JS has been executed?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a JS intensive website and I wanted to do this by loading the page, rendering the JS and then doing the scraping with BeautifulSoup.
I want to do this, if possible, on a RaspberryPi

I've tried using Requests-HTML, which worked fine for a while but couldn't get Python3.7 to run it on the Raspberry, due to memory limitations.
Then i tried using Selenium, with both Geckodriver, which isn't available for arm6 and I don't know how to compile for the Raspberry, and PhantomJS, which i couldn't get to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

- Use tool that could mimic browser and render the js parts of the page, like selenium
- Examine the page and see which requests to the backend are obtaining the data you need

I would go with the first approach if I need a general purpose tool, that can scrape data from all sorts of pages

And I would go with the second if I need to scrape pages from several sites and be done with it. If you provide some link I can try to help you with this.